# Set netbeans to recognise .tpl.php as smarty extension

Tags: php, plugins, netbeans, smarty

All my template files are with `.tpl.php` extension and I can't figure out how to associate smarty plugin to these kind of files. Overriding `.php` extension works but is not a good solution... Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are they `.php.tpl` or `.tpl.php`? Your title says one thing and your post says another.

Comment: Well, the file will interpreted as a php file because it ends with `.php` both in NetBeans and on the server. Seems pretty contradictory to use the `.tpl.php` extension instead of `.tpl` as the point of template engines is to limit the template designers programming capabilities.

Comment: that's a project from my work and i cant change the extensions.

Comment: Netbeans does not support `.` in extension setting, it seems it treats `.` as extension separator ignoring double extensions.